# Using header files to make an ADT: declaration of ‘int Queue::size()’ outside of class is not definition [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, oop

I've combed through Google and Stack Overflow looking for an answer to this problem. I know this is super basic, and I'm really irritated I can't figure out what is wrong. So my graduate professor wants us to make an implementation of a Queue for integers. Why? Because this is "Principles of Programming" and we're basically going over ever single little detail with super concise definitions. It's honestly the biggest waste of a three hour class I've ever had to take, but at least the teacher is good. Anyways, I've got the class definition in a .h file, which contains

```
#ifndef QUEUE_H
#define QUEUE_H


class Queue
{
        private:
                std::vector<int> myQueue;
        public:
                int push(int);
                int pop_front();
                int size();
                bool empty();
};

#endif
```

So, I feel like Queue::size() and Queue::empty are declared right? Well, in my queue.cpp file, I've got the details of these functions...

```
#include <vector>
#include "queue.h"

int Queue::push(int intToPush)
{
        myQueue.push_back(intToPush);
        return 0;
};

int Queue::pop_front()
{
        int front = myQueue.front();
        myQueue.erase(myQueue.begin());
        return front;
};
/*
int Queue::size(); <- It was these semicolons
{
        return myQueue.size();
};

bool Queue::empty(); <- This one too.
{
        return myQueue.empty();
};*/
```

And when I compile it like this, it does fine, but when I include those two that I have commented out, it gives the error I put in the title of this post.

I'm really sorry that this is so basic and stupid, but I can't find anything to help me and it really perplexes me that these functions are causing the compiler to say that their being declared outside of the class. I tried using the generic returns, 0 and false, and get the same compilation error.

Comment: As a general rule it helps to include the compile error in questions about compile errors.

Comment: I would have, I had already included it in the title of the post so I didn't want to be redundant.

Edit: also if someone else tried to google the compilation error, this way it's more likely to show up on Google so maybe they can get help too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the semicolon from the end of the function names in the cpp file and try compiling again.  You can also remove the semicolons trailing the terminating brackets of all of the function definitions.  They are not necessary.

Comment: Appreciate it man! I was taught that you always are supposed to put semicolons after a function definition by convention, even though it's not strictly required by the compiler, and to treat while-loops, for-loops, if-statements and the like as functions so my code is usually riddled with semicolons.

Comment: If I remember correctly some compilation modes (e.g. -pedantic) that enforce strict ANSI compliance will actually reject code where there are semicolons trailing closing function brackets.  I don't know how often such modes are used in practice, though.